# How to transfer better sqs queue messages into redshift?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-sqs, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a sqs queue, that my application constantly sends messages to (about 5-15 messages per second).
I need to take the messages data and put it in redshift.
Right now, I have background service which gets X messages from the queue every Y minutes, then the service put them in an s3 file, and transfer the data into redshift using the COPY command.

This implementation have some problems:

1. In my service, I get X messages at a time, and because of the sqs limits, amazon allow to receive only 10 messages at max at a time (meaning that if I want to get 1000 messages, I will need to make 100 network calls)
2. My service doesn't scale as the application scales -> when there will be 30 (or 300) messages per second, my service won't be able to handle all the messages.
3. Using aws firehose is a little inconvenient the way I see it, because SHARDS are not scalable (I will need to configure manually to add shards) but maybe I'm wrong here
   ...

A a result of those things, I need something that will be scalable and efficient as possible. any ideas?

Comment: What are your actual business requirements? How urgent is it that those messages appear in query results from Redshift? For example, could you simply load them once a day, or is it important that the data is available in Redshift within a few seconds or minutes? Also, how big are the messages? Do your queries on the messages look over _all_ historical messages, or do you tend to only query messages in the past day or so? Please note that Amazon Redshift is a data warehouse -- it is not intended for use as a transactional database. Why did you select Redshift for such a use-case?

Comment: How urgent is it that those messages appear in query results from Redshift? -> few minutes. message size is about 5kB. Do your queries on the messages look over all historical messages -> some of the queries look over all the data.

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose you have described, I think AWS would say that Kinesis [Data Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-streams/) plus Kinesis [Data Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose) is a more appropriate service than SQS.

Yes, like you said, you do have to configure the [shards](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-streams/pricing). But just one shard can handle 1000 incoming records/sec. Also there are ways to automate the scaling, for example like AWS have [documented here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/scaling-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-with-aws-application-auto-scaling/)

One further advantage of using Kinesis Data Firehose is you can create a delivery stream which pushes the data straight into Redshift if you wish.